# BigQuery - Listing partitions of the date partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Query -- SELECT partition_id from `Mydataset.Table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__`;
 gives below error-- Table "Mydataset.Table$**PARTITIONS_SUMMARY**" cannot include decorator`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below in Legacy SQL

```
SELECT project_id,
    dataset_id,
    table_id,
    partition_id,
    TIMESTAMP(creation_time/1000) AS creation_time
FROM [Mydataset.Table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

and below for Standard SQL

```
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME as pt
FROM `Mydataset.Table`
GROUP BY 1
```

which also works for Legacy SQL

```
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME as pt
FROM [Mydataset.Table]
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Big Query documentation says partition_id should work, not sure why it gives that error, I am noticing same error for select query from a date partition.

Comment: I think this only works for ingestion-time-partitioned tables.  The OP was asking about date partitions

Comment: @SteveFaiwiszewski - before downvoting  - check the year when question was asked as well as fact that it was accepted and quite upvoted by community

Comment: Does the answer STILL work today?  I don't think so.   Thus the answer as it stands today is rather misleading; it's irrelevant if it was correct at some point. If you'd like update it to state this is no longer applicable, and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @SteveFaiwiszewski - no worries. you might be right from the point of view of person with just 12 answers. but for person with more than 3600 answers it is just not feasible :o) I would suggest you to add your own answer to address the relevancy issue you see here

Answer (score 1):

Old question but with a new answer

```
select partition_id
from `Mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
where table_name = 'Table'
```

this is standard sql and your billing will be much less compared to using a `group by`